# How to configure valve in embedded tomcat?

Tags: tomcat8, embedded-tomcat-8

I need to configure valve in embedded tomcat http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/valve.html#Remote_IP_Valve
How to do it?

Answer (score 6):

It is part of Pipeline which is part of Host, so you would do:

```
    Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();

    Host host = new StandardHost();
    Valve valve = ...

    host.getPipeline().addValve(valve);
    tomcat.setHost(host);
```